# ObservableCollection adds an item and overrides the others

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I have this function:

```
ObservableCollection<TankstellenItem> completeList = new ObservableCollection<TankstellenItem>();
        for(var j = 0; j < listItem.Count; j++)
        {
            foreach (FuelItem fItem in listItem.ToList()[j].Fuels)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("HERE AGAIN: " + fItem.Price);
                TankstellenItem newItem = new TankstellenItem();
                ObservableCollection<FuelItem> fuelList = new ObservableCollection<FuelItem>();
                newItem = listItem.ToList()[j];
                newItem.Fuels = null;
                fuelList.Add(fItem);
                newItem.Fuels = fuelList;
                completeList.Add(newItem);
                Debug.WriteLine("PRICES: " + completeList.ToList()[0].Fuels[0].Price);
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("COMPLETELIST LENGTH: " + completeList.ToList()[0].Fuels[0].Price + " + " + completeList.ToList()[1].Fuels[0].Price);
```

and the outcome is:

```
LISTITEM LENGTH: 1
HERE AGAIN: 1,699
PRICES: 1,699
HERE AGAIN: 1,529
PRICES: 1,529
COMPLETELIST LENGTH: 1,529 + 1,529
```

As you can seein the foreach the Prices are different. But after the for-method the output is only 1,529 in every item. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: It's a bit hard to decipher but, for a start, I think you should get rid of all of the redundant .ToList() calls you're making.  That's just making copies of your arrrays (I'm guessing they're arrays) unneccesarily.  Also, you can declare variable "newItem" without having to assign it to a new object instance that's never used.

Comment: what is listItem here (type) ? how is it defined ?

Comment: the listItem is the original ObservableCollection<TankstellenItem>

Comment: What is the length of complete list at the end of the function because if you have more than one fuel it will add multiple parents

Comment: What is the implementation of `TankstellenItem.Fuels`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from your code, you want to retrieve all the `Fuel` objects from each TankstellenItem in your original list (`listItem`) and then put them into an ObservableCollection.

```
 // Create Complete List
 ObservableCollection<TankstellenItem> completeList = new ObservableCollection<TankstellenItem>();
 // Loop through each TankstellenItem in listItem
 foreach(TankstellenItem tItem in listItem) {
      // Create an ObservableCollection to store FuelItem objects
      ObservableCollection<FuelItem> fuelList = new ObservableCollection<FuelItem>();
      // Loop through each FuelItem in the current TankstellenItem
      foreach(FuelItem fItem in tItem) {
           // Add the FuelItem from current TankstellenItem to the ObservableCollection
           Debug.WriteLine("HERE AGAIN: " + fItem.Price);
           completeList.Add(new TankstellenItem() {
                // Add the FuelItem
                Fuels = new ObservableCollection<FuelItem>() { 
                     fItem,
                };
           }
      }

 }
```

Although, it might be easier, if you only care about the `FuelItem`s, to have a collection of the FuelItems instead of wrapping them inside a `TankstellenItem`.

```
 ObservableCollection<FuelItem> completeList = new ObservableCollection<FuelItem>();
 foreach(TankstellenItem tItem in listItem) {
      foreach(FuelItem fItem in tItem) {
           completeList.Add(fItem);
      }
 }
```

Comment: no, that is not really right. I want to put every FuelItem into one TankstellenItem. because in a Listbox I want show every TankstellenItem with all of the fuels in separate listItems. For exampl: I have an TankstellenItem with two Fuels. In the Listbox the first listboxItem is TankstellenItem with Fuel 1 and the second listboxItem is with Fuel2

Comment: You mean each `FuelItem` into its own `TankstellenItem`?

Comment: @newone I moved the adding to the list into the `foreach` so that it creates a new `TankstellenItem` for each `FuelItem`. Any particular reason why you can't just use a collection of `FuelItem`s instead of wrapping them in a `TankstellenItem` object?

Answer (score 0):

Linq might make this easier: Do you actually want

```
var completelist=listItem.SelectMany(
       i=>i.Fuels.Select(
          f=>new TankstellenItem { Fuels=new ObservableCollection<FuelItem>(new[] { f})}
       )
   ).ToList();
```